# Identify the Vertices and Lines around the edges of a free surface - Mesh/DiscreteGraphics

Tags: finite-element-method, mesh

To write a mesher that closes a mesh surface using an implied surface from a boundary spline curve and mesh generated using DiscreteGraphics, I need to identify the Vertices and Lines around the edges of a free surface. Is there a simple way to extract just this data using MeshCells?

Below is a sample mesh with two free edges/openings that I would like to extract this information from.

```
curv1 = {{3, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {-2, 0, 0}, {0, -2, 0}, {3, 0, 0}}; 
curv2 = {{2, 0, 5}, {1, 1, 2}, {0, 2, 2}, {-1, 0, 5}, {0, -2, 5}, {3, 0, 5}}; 
sur1 = BSplineSurface[{curv1, curv2}, SplineClosed -> {False, True},     SplineDegree -> 3]; 
DiscretizeGraphics[sur1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The presence of a seam in both @flinty's and @kglr's answer suggest that an invalid mesh (for FEM purposes) is being created by the OP's `DiscretizeGraphics` approach.  Rather than troubleshooting the meshing approach, I will present a structured meshing approach that eliminates the spurious edge artifact.

First, we will use a [`BSplineFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BSplineFunction.html) to map a structured UV map to the curved surface.

```
curv1 = {{3, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {-2, 0, 0}, {0, -2, 0}, {3, 
    0, 0}};
curv2 = {{2, 0, 5}, {1, 1, 2}, {0, 2, 2}, {-1, 0, 5}, {0, -2, 5}, {3, 
    0, 5}};
bsf1 = BSplineFunction[{curv1, curv2}, SplineClosed -> {False, True}, 
   SplineDegree -> 3];
```

The following workflow will create structure `MeshRegion`:

```
(* Import Required Package *)
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
(* Create a UV Tensor Product Grid *)
pointsToMesh[data_] :=
  MeshRegion[Transpose[{data}], 
   Line@Table[{i, i + 1}, {i, Length[data] - 1}]];
seg = pointsToMesh@Subdivide[0, 1, 36]
rp = RegionProduct[seg, seg]
(* Extract Coords from RegionProduct *)
crd = MeshCoordinates[rp];
(* Map coordinates to BSPlineFunction *)
crd2 = crd /. {{x_, y_} -> Chop[bsf1[x, y], 1*^-7]};
(*grab incidents RegionProduct mesh*)
inc = Delete[0] /@ MeshCells[rp, 2];
(* Convert Quads to Triangles *)
inc2 = Partition[
   Flatten[ inc /. {{i_, j_, k_, l_} -> {{i, j, k}, {i, k, l}}}], 3];
mrkrs = ConstantArray[1, First@Dimensions@inc2];
(* FEM Create BoundaryMesh *)
bm = ToBoundaryMesh["Coordinates" -> crd2, 
   "BoundaryElements" -> {TriangleElement[inc2, mrkrs]}];
(* Convert BoundaryMesh to MeshRegion *)
mr = MeshRegion[bm];
HighlightMesh[mr, Style[1, Orange]]
```

[image: Strucured Mesh]

The resulting mesh looks pretty good.

Now, we can apply @kglr's approach to see that we removed the spurious edge:

```
(* Apply kglr's Edge Extraction Method *)
boundaryedgeindices = 
  Flatten@Position[
    Length /@ mr["ConnectivityMatrix"[1, 2]]["AdjacencyLists"], 1];
HighlightMesh[mr, Style[{1, boundaryedgeindices}, Thick, Red]]
```

[image: Free Edges]

## Update: Top Surface 2D Mesh

In the comments, the OP had a question about capping the ends of the mesh.  Because the projected curve is not convex, a simple capping is not generally possible.  One possibility, is to create a [minimal surface](https://www.wolfram.com/language/12/nonlinear-finite-elements/interactively-solve-nonlinear-pdes.html?product=language).

The following workflow shows how to create a 2D mesh with nodes that are equivalenced with the 3D mesh by setting the Mesh Order to 1 and the `SteinerPoints` option to `False`.

```
(* Extract Coords from segment *)
crd2d = MeshCoordinates[seg];
(* Map coordinates to BSPlineFunction *)
crd2d2 = Flatten[
   crd2d /. {{x_} :> Chop[{bsf1[1, x][[1 ;; 2]]}, 1*^-7]}, 1];
(* grab incidents segmentr mesh *)
inc2d = Delete[0] /@ MeshCells[seg, 1];
(* Create Boundary Mesh *)
bm2d = ToBoundaryMesh["Coordinates" -> crd2d2, 
   "BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement[inc2d]}];
bm2d["Wireframe"]
(* Create 2D element mesh *)
m2d = ToElementMesh[bm2d, "MeshOrder" -> 1, "SteinerPoints" -> False];
m2d["Wireframe"]
```

To use the *Mathematica* example to create a minimal surface will require a little thought to specify the `DirichletCondition` because the curve is specified parametrically.  Since the OP has routines for calculating minimal surfaces, I will not go into it here.

[image: 2D Mesh]

## Update: Minimal Surface

The following workflow will solve for the [minimal surface](https://wolfram.com/xid/0bdpx7hg6-hvook1) using `NDSolveValue`.

```
(* convert bsf1 to x,y,z components *)
ztop0[v_?NumericQ] := Module[{val}, val = bsf1[1, v]; Last@val];
zmin = First@NMinimize[ztop0[t], {t, 0, 1}];
zmax = First@NMaximize[ztop0[t], {t, 0, 1}];
zmid = Mean[{zmin, zmax}];
xtop[v_?NumericQ] := Module[{val}, val = bsf1[1, v]; First@val];
ytop[v_?NumericQ] := Module[{val}, val = bsf1[1, v]; val[[2]]];
ztop[v_?NumericQ] := Module[{val}, val = bsf1[1, v]; Last@val - zmid];
(* Use Nearest to find v given x,y *)
nf = Nearest[
   Table[{xtop[t], ytop[t]}, {t, 0, 1, .0001}] -> 
    Table[t, {t, 0, 1, .0001}]];
(* calculate z given x,y for DirichletCondition *)
fz[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := ztop[First@nf[{x, y}]]
(* Minimal Surface https://wolfram.com/xid/0bdpx7hg6-hvook1 *)
ufun = NDSolveValue[{-Inactive[Div][(1/Sqrt[1 + \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(∇\), \({x, y}\)]\(u[x, y]\)\).\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(∇\), \({x, y}\)]\(u[x, y]\)\)]) Inactive[Grad][
         u[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] == 0, 
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == fz[x, y], True]}, 
   u, {x, y} ∈ m2d];
```

Now, we can convert the 2D mesh to a 3D boundary mesh using the minimal surface solution for the z coordinates:

```
(* create and display minimal surface boundary mesh *)
c3d = Join[m2d["Coordinates"], List /@ (ufun["ValuesOnGrid"] + zmid), 
   2];
bmtop = ToBoundaryMesh["Coordinates" -> c3d, 
   "BoundaryElements" -> m2d["MeshElements"]];
Show[bm["Wireframe"["MeshElementStyle" -> {FaceForm[Green]}]], 
 bmtop["Wireframe"["MeshElementStyle" -> {FaceForm[Red]}]]]
```

[image: Top Surface Mesh]

You can see that the free surface nodes align well with the base mesh.

Comment: That looks great, Tim! Do you know how to close the ends of this irregular tube with a mesh?

Comment: @mh2000 Sorry for the delay.  I was at my niece's wedding yesterday.  I don't think there is a unique way to cap the surfaces or a unique surface for that matter.  If the enclosing curve is convex, we could attempt a simple cap with the centroid. We could attempt a minimal surface as shown [here](https://www.wolfram.com/language/12/nonlinear-finite-elements/interactively-solve-nonlinear-pdes.html?product=language).

Comment: Thanks, Tim! That is exactly what I was thinking about doing! If you have an idea for creating the base mesh, I'd love to see it. I have a number of routines for doing the minimal surface calculations.

Comment: I updated the answer to show how to create an equivalenced cap mesh in 2D.

Comment: Doing this in Mathematica is really stretching my Mathematica knowledge, but trying to digest this, the first question I have (I asked somewhere above this at one point), how did you determine that the lower edge was going to be the first 36 boundary edge indices (I can confirm this using "HighlightMesh[mr, 
 Style[{1, Take[boundaryedgeindices, 36]}, Thick, Red]]")?

Comment: @mh2000 Although I used `RegionProduct` to create a "structured mesh", it is fortuitous that it was the first 36 elements since I don't know the inner workings of the internal functions.  You probably need an actual test to be sure.  Also, I added a minimal surface example for the top surface.

Comment: Thank you, Tim (and all!)! You have really helped me get going on this project! I'll think about checking for the top or bottom boundary. I think I can test for group of one closed loop based on Lines and then assume the other vertices make up the other. Easier still is the fact that the structured mesh seems to put an equal number of nodes on each boundary curve! If the numbering is separated by a gap like this, you can just Sort and Take 1/2 and -1/2! I think I'll need to visually verify that it works, but this is a great start!

Answer (score 7):

Find the lines on the mesh polygons that are not shared with other polygons:

```
curv1 = {{3, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {-2, 0, 0}, {0, -2, 0}, {3, 0, 0}};
curv2 = {{2, 0, 5}, {1, 1, 2}, {0, 2, 2}, {-1, 0, 5}, {0, -2, 5}, {3, 0, 5}};
sur1 = BSplineSurface[{curv1, curv2}, SplineClosed -> {False, True}, SplineDegree -> 3];
mesh = DiscretizeGraphics[sur1];
cells = MeshCells[mesh, 2][[All, 1]];
lines = Join @@ ((Sort /@ Subsets[#, {2}]) & /@ cells);
edgecells = Select[Tally[lines], Last[#] == 1 &][[All, 1]];
coords = MeshCoordinates[mesh];
edgelines = Line[{coords[[First[#]]], coords[[Last[#]]]}] & /@ edgecells;
Graphics3D[{{EdgeForm[None], Opacity[.5], mesh}, Red, Thick, 
  edgelines}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image: mesh hole edges]

Note there is a seam in the mesh because the mesh is not connected there.

Comment: Thank you! Much smarter than the road I was going down (comparing vertices to the splines with a tolerance). Is there an easy way to close that seam? Also, how to separate the upper and lower edges?

Answer (score 7):

**Update:** Two alternative, more direct, ways to get the boundary edges:

**1.** Use the property `"EdgeFaceConnectivityRules"` and select the edges connected to `0`:

```
be1 = Keys @ Select[#[[1]] == 0 &] @ Association[ mr["EdgeFaceConnectivityRules"]]

be1 == boundaryedges
```

> ```
> True
> ```

**2.** Use the property `"ConnectivityMatrix"[1, 2]"` (which gives a `SparseArray` where entry $ij$ is 1 iff  1-dimensional element $i$ is connected to 2-dimensional element $j$) and select the rows that contain a single element:

```
be2 = Flatten @ 
  Position[Length /@ mr["ConnectivityMatrix"[1, 2]]["AdjacencyLists"],  1];

be2 == boundaryedges
```

> ```
> True
> ```

**Original answer:**

You can process `mr["FaceEdgeConnectivityRules"]` to identify edges connected to a single face:

```
mr = DiscretizeGraphics[sur1];

boundaryedges = Keys @ Select[EqualTo @ 1] @
    Counts @ Flatten @ Values @ mr["FaceEdgeConnectivityRules"];

HighlightMesh[mr, {1, boundaryedges}, PlotTheme -> "Lines"]
```

[image]

Then we can use `mr["EdgeVertexConnectivityRules"]` to identify the vertices incident to `boundaryedges`:

```
boundaryvertices = Union @@ (boundaryedges /. mr["EdgeVertexConnectivityRules"]);

HighlightMesh[mr, 
 Style[{0, boundaryvertices}, PointSize[Medium], Red], 
 PlotTheme -> "Lines"]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. Where did you find this property? I can't find it in the documentation.

Comment: @flinty, `mr["Properties"]` list a number of intriguing properties. None are documented; so trial/error is the only way to explore. (Over the last few versions/updates  more and more of these properties are working.)